# How to create different instances using Singleton pattern?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, singleton

I need to build a simple app like shopping cart.

**main.cpp**

```
int main()
{
    Cart cart;
    // add items
    cart.addItem("Shirt", ItemType:Clothing);
    cart.addItem("Xbox", ItemType::Entertainment);
    cart.addItem("Bowl", ItemType::Cooking);
    // print item
    cart.printItems();
    Item::destroy();
}
```

**Item.h**

```
enum ItemType
{
    Cooking,
    Clothing,
    Entertainment
};

class Item
{
private: 
    Item(const std::string& name, const ItemType& itemType);
    static Item* m_instance;
    std::string m_name;
    ItemType m_itemType;

public:
    static Item *getInstance(const std::string& name, const ItemType& itemType);    
    static void destroy();
    const std::string& getName() const;
    const ItemType& getItemType() const;
    void print() const;
};
```

**Item.cpp**

```
Item* Item::m_instance = nullptr;
Item::Item(const std::string& name, const ItemType& itemType)
{
    m_name = name;
    m_itemType = itemType;
}

Item* Item::getInstance(const std::string& name, const ItemType& itemType)
{
    if (!m_instance) {
        m_instance = new Item(name, itemType);
    }
    return m_instance;
}

void Item::destroy()
{
    delete m_instance;
    m_instance = nullptr;
}

void Item::print() const
{
    std::cout << "Item name: " << m_name << std::endl;
}
```

**Cart.h**

```
class Cart
{
public:
    Cart();
    ~Cart();

    void addItem(const std::string& name, const ItemType& itemType);
    void printItems();

private:
    std::vector<Item*> m_itemList = {};
};
```

**Cart.cpp**

```
void Cart::addItem(const std::string& name, const ItemType& itemType)
{
    Item *newItem = Item::getInstance(name, itemType);
    m_itemList.push_back(newItem);  
}

void Cart::printItems()
{
    std::cout << "Items" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < m_itemList.size(); i++)
    {
        m_itemList[i]->print();
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

When I run this code, the result is

`Item name: Shirt`

`Item name: Shirt`

`Item name: Shirt`

what I need is

`Item name: Shirt`

`Item name: Xbox`

`Item name: Bowl`

I am learning design pattern. I know the purpose of that is to create only one instance. In this example I should use singleton pattern. But I do not know where I am wrong, so I receive this result. Could you tell me where I should correct in my code? Many thanks!

Comment: No class you've shown here seems like a good candidate for singleton, and especially not `Item`.

Comment: Isn't _multiple instance_ and _singleton_ a bit contradictorily? Do you mean something like _unique instance_ in a set or map?

Comment: @FredLarson Maybe I dont understand singleton good enough. The requirement of this example is the class `Item` should remain as I defined, and how can I receive the desired result as above (not, `Shirt`, `Shirt`, `Shirt`, but `Shirt`, `Xbox`, `Bowl`). I don't really know where I am wrong :(

Comment: In terms of _design patterns_ I believe you want a [_Factory_](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/creational_patterns), which in turn can be implemented as a _Singleton_ or a _Factory Method_. The paricular problem is in fact _`static Item* m_instance;`_ which allows only one `Item` at a time, where you need many of these.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: sorry I wrote not clear or maybe I understand singleton not good enough. `multiple instance` here I mean, we have only one `item` instance at a time, we do not create many instances. But this item has different "value" at each time. In my case, the instance has only 1 value, that is wrong and undesired. But I do not know how to correct my code. :)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I am really new with design pattern. Could you please help me how to adjust my `Item` so that it has factory pattern?

Comment: @gnase Read a bit at that site I linked for you, may be things become clearer then. To get the output you want, you definitely need more than one instance of `Item`, there's no way out.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: thank you for your suggestion! I will try.

Comment: @gnase you are adding multiple "items" to the cart, so it simply doesn't make sense for there to be only 1 `Item` object in memory, you need multiple `Item` objects. So using a singleton design for `Item` makes no sense. `Item *newItem = Item::getInstance(name, itemType);` needs to be `Item *newItem = new Item(name, itemType);` instead, unless you get rid of `Item::m_instance` altogether and change `Item::getInstance()` to return `new Item(name, itemType)` every time it is called.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I have read the link you mentioned. But the problem here is the constructor of `Item` was defined as `private` and I can not change that. It is the requirement. Therefore, after I read the link you mentioned I still do not know how to work with it. Because when I want to add an item, I want to initialize an `item`, I must use the `getInstance`. That is my problem :(

Comment: @gnase An abstract class with a `private` constructor would be a bit of useless, no? But well, with `getInstance()` you still can hand out pointers created with `new`, just don't store these in the `static Item* m_instance;`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: ok, I know the singleton design in my case is a wrong way to go. But the problem is the constructor of `item` is defined as private, I can not change that, so when I want to create an item, i have to call `getInstance`. With my very little knowledge, I do not have another way right now :(

Comment: @gnase I actually covered that in my earlier comment: "*..., unless you get rid of `Item::m_instance` altogether and **change `Item::getInstance()` to return `new Item(name, itemType)` every time it is called**.*"

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: thank you very much, I have made it! But then I ask myself what is the meaning of defining constructor as private in this case, meanwhile we can not use singleton for this... :)

Comment: @RemyLebeau: thank you, I have made it. Have a nice day! :)

Comment: @gnase using a private constructor means outside code can't create `Item` objects directly. This allows you to restrict WHO can create `Item` objects, HOW `Item` objects are created, WHAT parameters can be used to create `Item` objects, etc.